# how i convert string index to integer index

Tags: python, pandas, string

dataframe:

| cater | rating |
| --- | --- |
| a | 2.5 |
| b | 4 |
| c | 3 |
| a | 4 |
| a | 2.5 |
| b | 4 |

what i want:

| cater | rating | average |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2.5 | 3.25 |
| b | 4 | 3.5 |
| c | 3 | 3 |
| a | 4 | 3.25 |
| b | 2.5 | 3.5 |
| b | 4 | 3.5 |

how I convert cater index to integer index?

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to self join your dataframe with a grouped version of itself. This is achievable by using `pd.merge()` with your dataframe as the left table variable and groupby dataframe as your right table variable.

```
>>> df
   cater  rating
0      1     2.5
1      2     4.0
2      3     3.0
3      1     4.0
4      2     2.5
5      2     4.0
>>> df2 = df.groupby('cater', as_index=False).mean()
>>> df2
   cater  rating
0      1    3.25
1      2    3.50
2      3    3.00
>>> df3 = pd.merge(df, df2, on='cater', suffixes=('', '_average'))
>>> df3.assign(cater = df3['cater'].map({1:'a',2:'b',3:'c'}))
  cater  rating  rating_average
0     a     2.5            3.25
1     a     4.0            3.25
2     b     4.0            3.50
3     b     2.5            3.50
4     b     4.0            3.50
5     c     3.0            3.00
```

Comment: i changed the question, would you mind edit it again?

Comment: sure, please check on the updated answer @Leo

Answer (score 0):

You can use this,

```
import pandas as pd

Input = "yourdataframe.xlsx"

df1 = pd.read_excel(Input, sheet_name = ' ')

df2 = df1.groupby('cater', as_index=False).mean().reset_index(drop = True)

df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = 'cater', how = 'left')

df3.columns = ['cater', 'rating', 'average']
```